# Investigating AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

I'm trying to get to the bottom of a AmbiguousMatchException, I've done a code review and it hasn't yet turned up anything helpful.

I thought this was related to this EF bug - [Can't map two classes with same name from different namespace](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483) and have made code changes, which could possibly have created the problem since our last deployment.  I've trying to add a object to a Entity, simply;

```
var request = new ApplicationRequest
{
   Name = "Test Application"
   // ... many more Properties
};
var context = new DataContext();
context.ApplicationRequests.Add(request);
```

Digging around the debugging objects returned but cannot find anything which links to the actual Type or Property name which is causing the problem.

[image: Ambiguous Match Record Debugger]

My call stack gives little information away;

[image: Stack Trace]

Running GetType in immediate window before *context.ApplicationRequests.Add(request);*

```
applicationRequest.GetType();
{Name = "ApplicationRequest" FullName = "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest"}
    [System.RuntimeType]: {Name = "ApplicationRequest" FullName = "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest"}
    base {System.Reflection.MemberInfo}: {Name = "ApplicationRequest" FullName = "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest"}
    Assembly: {EntityModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest, EntityModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "Object" FullName = "System.Object"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    DeclaringMethod: 'applicationRequest.GetType().DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    DeclaringType: null
    FullName: "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest"
    GenericParameterAttributes: 'applicationRequest.GetType().GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericParameterPosition: 'applicationRequest.GetType().GenericParameterPosition' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[0]}
    GUID: {c48e0605-6d74-388d-b21d-2fb630b1220e}
    HasElementType: false
    IsAbstract: false
    IsAnsiClass: true
    IsArray: false
    IsAutoClass: false
    IsAutoLayout: true
    IsByRef: false
    IsClass: true
    IsCOMObject: false
    IsConstructedGenericType: false
    IsContextful: false
    IsEnum: false
    IsExplicitLayout: false
    IsGenericParameter: false
    IsGenericType: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    IsImport: false
    IsInterface: false
    IsLayoutSequential: false
    IsMarshalByRef: false
    IsNested: false
    IsNestedAssembly: false
    IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
    IsNestedFamily: false
    IsNestedFamORAssem: false
    IsNestedPrivate: false
    IsNestedPublic: false
    IsNotPublic: false
    IsPointer: false
    IsPrimitive: false
    IsPublic: true
    IsSealed: false
    IsSecurityCritical: true
    IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
    IsSecurityTransparent: false
    IsSerializable: false
    IsSpecialName: false
    IsUnicodeClass: false
    IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    Module: {EntityModel.dll}
    Namespace: "EntityModel"
    ReflectedType: null
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: null
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "ApplicationRequest" FullName = "EntityModel.ApplicationRequest"}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried using full path to the application object? Is the type the one you are expecting if you run request.GetType() in the immediate window?

Comment: Could your class definition have some sort of duplicate property / method? Just wild guessing here.

Comment: Been looking for the offending entry for hours, hoping to find some more debugging information.

Comment: Could you share the applicationRequest class? Does this exception occur with all the different entities you have, or just the `ApplicationRequest`? Have you done any changes to the namespaces or some other structural change since the last time it worked? If yes, then what?

Comment: I can't share the full class, although I've gone through a looked. There's no clashing between properties and navigation properties. I've done some namespace changes since last time, I installed Resharper and that recommended them. I've since moved any external model namespace out of my Domain. Yes, I've notice I'm getting a Ambigious at another point in my schema. Is it possible to diagnose what is causing the problem?